# Spliting applicaiton to microservice avoid SQL Deadlock

Tags: python, microservices

I'm currently little bit stuck finding what can I use to achieve my goal. I have an app that is designed to query "work" from database and it also locks ( just literally write "locked" to Status row ) the lines it is working on, so other instances doesn't work on the same thing...  Same goes for when its done it writes the result back ( different table )

I'm running this app in many instances an I did everything I could to avoid deadlock, but from time to time it always happens ( it is handled in the app so no big deal but its annoying to see it there)

What I was thinking is to create separate running app with restAPI ( using FLASK ? ) that would upon request get back x values for worker to work with ( while the app would lock them in the DB as well ) .. this should solve the deadlock issue since only one process would write to the DB.. But what I'm not clear about is how it will handle bigger load, like 50 requests at once ... I need to somehow serialize the requests so I don't end up in the same situation...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Use a task queue like celery or at least a message queue like RabbitMQ instead of a database to handle your tasks.

Comment: Tanks @KlausD. I'll give it a read.